# An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, sentry

I started getting the following errors after adding the `sentry` plugin in plugins section and performing `./gradlew build`

```
id 'io.sentry.jvm.gradle' version '3.13.0'
```

We already had id `'com.github.hierynomus.license'` version '0.16.1' plugin definition and a license.gradle file in the local directory as well.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':licenseMain' (type 'LicenseCheck').
  - In plugin 'com.hierynomus.gradle.license.LicenseBasePlugin' type 'com.hierynomus.gradle.license.tasks.LicenseCheck' property 'header' specifies file '/Users/user/work/projects/con/cfc/LICENSE' which doesn't exist.
    
    Reason: An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Make sure the file exists before the task is called.
      2. Make sure that the task which produces the file is declared as an input.
    
    For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#input_file_does_not_exist in the Gradle documentation.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/user/work/projects/con/cfc/build/generated/sentry'.
    
    Reason: Task ':licenseMain' uses this output of task ':generateSentryDebugMetaPropertiesjava' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':generateSentryDebugMetaPropertiesjava' as an input of ':licenseMain'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':generateSentryDebugMetaPropertiesjava' from ':licenseMain' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':generateSentryDebugMetaPropertiesjava' from ':licenseMain' using Task#mustRunAfter.
    
    For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency in the Gradle documentation.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/user/work/projects/con/cfc/build/generated/sentry'.
    
    Reason: Task ':licenseMain' uses this output of task ':collectExternalDependenciesForSentry' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':collectExternalDependenciesForSentry' as an input of ':licenseMain'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':collectExternalDependenciesForSentry' from ':licenseMain' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':collectExternalDependenciesForSentry' from ':licenseMain' using Task#mustRunAfter.
    
    For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency in the Gradle documentation.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs on newer Gradle versions and is related to the caching. I haven't used those plugins, but usually you should be able to "fix" the problem by explicitly defining `dependsOn()` or in some cases `inputs.files()` (which has been already stated in the error)

Judging by the error message you should be able to resolve the problem with the following code:

```
tasks {
  // possible solution 1
  named("licenseMain") {
    inputs.files(tasks.named("generateSentryDebugMetaPropertiesjava"))
    inputs.files(tasks.named("collectExternalDependenciesForSentry"))
  }
  // possible solution 2
  named("licenseMain") {
    dependsOn(tasks.named("generateSentryDebugMetaPropertiesjava"))
    dependsOn(tasks.named("collectExternalDependenciesForSentry"))
  }
}
```

As for the error `An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't`, based on what the error suggests afterwards, the file might not be present, because another gradle task is providing it (i.e. `generateSentryDebugMetaPropertiesjava` or `collectExternalDependenciesForSentry`) but since that task is not executed before `licenseMain` -- the file does not exist.

Comment: ./gradlew clean build raises Could not find method named() for arguments [licenseMain, build_10dbzuxb9ugjfdv0ff1ngyi6z$_run_closure5$_closure21@4ea69061] on task ':tasks' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.TaskReportTask.

Comment: The code above is for `build.gradle.kts`. You probably need to convert it into groovy.